# CRUD con DAPPER en MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

quisiera saber como puedo agregar un editar y buscar con biblioteca Dapper, ya hice el metodo de insertar y eliminar. Estoy trabajando con MVC C# VS 2013

#### CONTROLADOR

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers

{

    public class Default1Controller : Controller

{

        [ActionName("Index")]
        [HttpGet]

        public ActionResult GetIndex()
        {
            NameValueCollection queryString = Request.QueryString;

            IDbConnection database = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString);

            if (queryString["eliminar"] != null)
            {
                database.Delete<Prueba>(int.Parse(queryString["eliminar"]));
                ViewData["notificacion"] = "Registro eliminado correctamente.";
            }


            return View();
        }
        // POST: /Default1/
        [ActionName("Index")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostIndex(FormCollection form)
        {
            string cs = form["txtcod_sis"];
            string co = form["txtcod_obra"];
            string no = form["txtnom_obra"];
            string ao = form["txtanyo_obra"];

            IDbConnection DB = new SqlConnection(Config.ConnectionString);

            Prueba p1 = new Prueba();
            p1.CodObra = co;
            p1.NomObra = no;
            p1.AnyoObra = int.Parse(ao);

            int? id = DB.Insert(p1);

            ViewData["notificacion"] = "Registro agregado correctamente (ID " + id + ").";

            IEnumerable<dynamic> captaciones = DB.Query("select * from prueba");
            ViewData["captaciones"] = captaciones;



            return View();
        }



    }
}
```

#### INDEX

Index


    FORMULARIO PRUEBA

```
@{      
    if (ViewData["notificacion"] != null)
    { 
        <h4>@ViewData["notificacion"]</h4>
    }   
}

<div> 
    <form id="form1" method="post">

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Agregar</legend>
            <table width="40">
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Codigo Obra</label></td>
                    <td><label>Nombre Obra</label></td>
                    <td><label>Año Obra</label></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtcod_obra" maxlength="10" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtnom_obra" maxlength="10" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="txtanyo_obra" min="1900" max="2050" maxlength="4" /></td>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <p>
                <input name="Button1" type="submit" value="enviar" />

            </p>
        </fieldset>

    </form>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos Captación</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>ID Obra</label></td>
                <td><label>Código</label></td>
                <td><label>Nombre</label></td>
                <td><label>Año</label></td>
            </tr>

            @if (ViewData["captaciones"] != null)
            {
                IEnumerable<dynamic> captaciones = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)ViewData["captaciones"];

                foreach (dynamic captacion in captaciones)
                { 
                    <tr>
                        <td><label>@captacion.id_sis</label></td>
                        <td><label>@captacion.cod_obra</label></td>
                        <td><label>@captacion.nom_obra</label></td>
                        <td><label>@captacion.anyo_obra</label></td>
                        <td><a href="?editar=@captacion.id_sis"><small>Editar</small></a></td>
                        <td><a href="?eliminar=@captacion.id_sis"><small>Eliminar</small></a></td>

                    </tr>
                } 
            } 

        </table>
    </fieldset>

</div>
```

#### Modelo

namespace WebApplication1.Models.NBI
{
    [Table("prueba")]

```
public class Prueba

{
     [Key]

     [Column("id_sis")]        
    public string IdSis { get; set; }
     [Column("cod_obra")]
    public string CodObra { get; set; }
     [Column("nom_obra")]
    public string NomObra { get; set; }
     [Column("anyo_obra")]
    public int? AnyoObra { get; set; }

}
```

}